# cisco ip phone 7811 cnu unpack

Tags: disassembly, assembly

```
root@kali:/var/tmp# /usr/local/bin/binwalk 1.cnu 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
859773        0xD1E7D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD8, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 143729976 bytes
2167077       0x211125        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xA2, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 512 bytes
2462556       0x25935C        Unix path: /usr/local/trace/log.properties
2491824       0x2605B0        Neighborly text, "neighborDatater of ipV4Buffer"
2496776       0x261908        Unix path: /usr/local/etc/ppid.conf
2498956       0x26218C        Unix path: /usr/local/etc/localtime
2541156       0x26C664        HTML document header
2541164       0x26C66C        HTML document footer
2548552       0x26E348        Base64 standard index table
2633552       0x282F50        PARity archive data - file number 29296
2673864       0x28CCC8        XML document, version: "1.0"
2818416       0x2B0170        XML document, version: "1.0"
2818768       0x2B02D0        XML document, version: "1.0"
2850344       0x2B7E28        XML document, version: "1.0"
2850544       0x2B7EF0        XML document, version: "1.0"
2852484       0x2B8684        XML document, version: "1.0"
2907869       0x2C5EDD        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Glenn Randers-Pehrson"
2907918       0x2C5F0E        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1996-1997 Andreas Dilger"
2907960       0x2C5F38        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1995-1996 Guy Eric Schalnat, Group 42, Inc."
2914752       0x2C79C0        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
2918848       0x2C89C0        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
2925631       0x2CA43F        Copyright string: "Copyright 1995-2005 Mark Adler "
2943375       0x2CE98F        Neighborly text, "neighbor 1 malloc failed MsgQue has not been created : %m "
2943423       0x2CE9BF        Neighborly text, "neighbor: inetdMsgQue has not been created : %m r: msgsnd failed : %m "
2943479       0x2CE9F7        Neighborly text, "neighbor: msgsnd failed : %m pQue open failed : %m "
2943527       0x2CEA27        Neighborly text, "neighbor: cdpRspQue open failed : %m ailed "
2943571       0x2CEA53        Neighborly text, "neighbor 2 malloc failed s response : %m "
2943603       0x2CEA73        Neighborly text, "neighbor: error receiving status response : %m ll info"
3016112       0x2E05B0        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
3017151       0x2E09BF        Copyright string: "Copyright 1995-1998 Jean-loup Gailly "
3020507       0x2E16DB        Copyright string: "Copyright 1995-1998 Mark Adler "
3979099       0x3CB75B        Unix path: /midp/io/j2me/ssl
4078794       0x3E3CCA        Neighborly text, "NeighborIDrIPv6"
4078822       0x3E3CE6        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPrPort"
4078850       0x3E3D02        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPv6orID"
4078878       0x3E3D1E        Neighborly text, "NeighborPortorIP"
4078907       0x3E3D3B        Neighborly text, "NeighborIDrIPv6"
4078935       0x3E3D57        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPrPort"
4078963       0x3E3D73        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPv6RT_INFO_MAX_INDEX"
4078991       0x3E3D8F        Neighborly text, "NeighborPortNTEGER"
4081214       0x3E463E        Neighborly text, "NeighborInfoml"
4081584       0x3E47B0        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPv4AddressghborPortID"
4081604       0x3E47C4        Neighborly text, "NeighborIPv6Addresstatus"
4081624       0x3E47D8        Neighborly text, "NeighborDeviceIDs"
4081644       0x3E47EC        Neighborly text, "NeighborPortID"
4217515       0x405AAB        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xBF, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 25430 bytes
4238176       0x40AB60        mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, algorithm: xTEA, mode: CBC, keymode: SHA-1 hash
4244703       0x40C4DF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 306730334 bytes
4254959       0x40ECEF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 22638 bytes
4261863       0x4107E7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 19060 bytes
4337995       0x42314B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC8, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 55919 bytes
4358895       0x4282EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 16244 bytes
4366171       0x429F5B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 61006 bytes
4821851       0x49935B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 60970 bytes
4822767       0x4996EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 34346 bytes
4828939       0x49AF0B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x88, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 25399 bytes
4840779       0x49DD4B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 30250 bytes
4848731       0x49FC5B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD8, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 18549 bytes
4859631       0x4A26EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 36705 bytes
4869955       0x4A4F43        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 12353 bytes
5340435       0x517D13        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x90, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 34420 bytes
5345091       0x518F43        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 675291968 bytes
5363439       0x51D6EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 828140908 bytes
5386331       0x52305B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 139399747 bytes
5391071       0x5242DF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 28269 bytes
5391327       0x5243DF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 28781 bytes
5398339       0x525F43        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 895370334 bytes
5418207       0x52ACDF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 31831 bytes
5423415       0x52C137        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB4, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 38193 bytes
5539594       0x54870A        mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, algorithm: xTEA, mode: CBC, keymode: 8bit
5692739       0x56DD43        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 63810 bytes
5695543       0x56E837        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB4, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 289607235 bytes
5709039       0x571CEF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 62797 bytes
5716455       0x5739E7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 2126 bytes
5719867       0x57473B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 53619 bytes
5724903       0x575AE7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 62009 bytes
5730635       0x57714B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 25399 bytes
5744607       0x57A7DF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 40759 bytes
5956931       0x5AE543        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 28268 bytes
5964859       0x5B043B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 35937 bytes
5976887       0x5B3337        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB4, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 40259 bytes
5977063       0x5B33E7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 40515 bytes
5977319       0x5B34E7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 41027 bytes
5987083       0x5B5B0B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x88, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 829402188 bytes
6020875       0x5BDF0B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x88, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 52326 bytes
6208487       0x5EBBE7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 54315 bytes
6233327       0x5F1CEF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 13899 bytes
6250043       0x5F5E3B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB8, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 14172 bytes
6257939       0x5F7D13        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x90, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 51251 bytes
6465263       0x62A6EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 31831 bytes
6481135       0x62E4EF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 30250 bytes
6481419       0x62E60B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x88, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 31018 bytes
6482655       0x62EADF        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5C, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 34346 bytes
6487527       0x62FDE7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 54862 bytes
6495251       0x631C13        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x90, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 61006 bytes
6496311       0x632037        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB4, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 8783 bytes
6649431       0x657657        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC8, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 167772160 bytes
6649887       0x65781F        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD0, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 167772160 bytes
6650271       0x65799F        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB4, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 100663296 bytes
6712044       0x666AEC        Base64 standard index table
```

Result is:

```
root@kali:/var/tmp/_1.cnu.extracted# ls
211125       4107E7.lzma  518F43.lzma  5739E7.lzma  5EBBE7.lzma  657657.lzma
211125.lzma  42314B.lzma  51D6EF       57473B.lzma  5F1CEF.lzma  65781F
26C664.html  4282EF.lzma  51D6EF.lzma  575AE7.lzma  5F5E3B.lzma  65781F.lzma
28CCC8.xml   429F5B.lzma  52305B.lzma  57714B.lzma  5F7D13.lzma  65799F
2B0170.xml   49935B.lzma  5242DF.lzma  57A7DF.lzma  62A6EF.lzma  65799F.lzma
2B02D0.xml   4996EF.lzma  5243DF.lzma  5AE543.lzma  62E4EF.lzma  D1E7D
2B7E28.xml   49AF0B.lzma  525F43.lzma  5B043B.lzma  62E60B.lzma  D1E7D.lzma
2B7EF0.xml   49DD4B.lzma  52ACDF.lzma  5B3337.lzma  62EADF.lzma
2B8684.xml   49FC5B.lzma  52C137.lzma  5B33E7.lzma  62FDE7.lzma
405AAB.lzma  4A26EF.lzma  56DD43.lzma  5B34E7.lzma  631C13.lzma
40C4DF.lzma  4A4F43.lzma  56E837.lzma  5B5B0B.lzma  632037.lzma
40ECEF.lzma  517D13.lzma  571CEF.lzma  5BDF0B.lzma  657657
root@kali:/var/tmp/_1.cnu.extracted#
```

I want to know how to unpack LZMA files or cnu files

Answer (score 2):

Binwalk has already unpacked the LZMA files for you. For example, the LZMA compressed file `D1E7D.lzma` was decompressed and the decompressed data was saved to the file `D1E7D`.

From the binwalk output, this looks very much like an RTOS based firmware. In particular, check the first two decompressed LZMA files for executable code (binwalk's `-A` option will do a quick check for common opcodes from various architectures).

Also note the base64 and CRC32 tables found in the main firmware image, which suggests that there is probably uncompressed executable code in the main firmware image as well.

Most of those LZMA files toward the end of the firmware image are probably compressed HTML / JS / CSS / image files.

It's hard to know without looking at the firmware, but it appears that this firmware is already "unpacked". But you need to find the executable code, figure out the code's expected load address, and start disassembling and reversing the code.